# Contar el numero de coincidencias de un valor tipo string en un arreglo de caracteres c++

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de ver cantas veces se repiten unas palabras en un arreglo de `[5][5]`, pero aún no encuentro la manera de verificar los datos si son de tipo carácter, las palabras a contar son las siguientes:

- muy bien
- bien
- aceptable
- mal
- pesimo

Cada una de esas palabras se almacena en mi siguiente arreglo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void opiniones(string infoEncuesta [5][5]);


int main(){

string infoEncuesta [5][5]={
        { "mal", "bien", "bien", "mal", "pesimo"},
        {"muy bien", "bien","aceptablee","mal", "pesimo"},
        {"aceptable", "mal","mal","mal", "mal"},
        {"", "","","", ""},
        {"", "","","", ""}
};

opiniones(infoEncuesta);

return 0;
}
```

cree una funcion llamada opiniones donde mando a llamar al arreglo y hago un recorrido con un ciclo donde me muestra los datos parecidos, peero el problema es que solo me lee datos de la primera fila

```
void opiniones(string infoEncuesta [5][5]) {
int columna;

string nombre;
cout << "Ingrese el nombre de la calificacion : "<<endl;
cin>>nombre;
for (int i = 1; i<5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        if (nombre==infoEncuesta[1][j])
        {
            columna=j++;
        }
    }
}
cout<<infoEncuesta[0][columna]<<"\n"<<infoEncuesta[1][columna] 
<<"\n"<<infoEncuesta[2][columna]<<"\n"<<infoEncuesta[3][columna] 
<<"\n"<<infoEncuesta[4][columna]<<"\n-------------------------" 
<<endl;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: cree una funcion llamada opiniones donde mando a llamar al arreglo para hacer un recorrido modificare la pregunta para mostrarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no encuentro la manera de verificar los datos si son de tipo carácter

No tienes que verificar nada: los datos serán del tipo que les pidas que sean. En tu caso has creado los datos como tipo *objeto cadena* (`std::string`):

```
//                       v  v <--- Cinco filas y cinco columnas
    string infoEncuesta [5][5]={
//  ^^^^^^ <--- Tipo cadena
            { "mal", "bien", "bien", "mal", "pesimo"},
            {"muy bien", "bien","aceptablee","mal", "pesimo"},
            {"aceptable", "mal","mal","mal", "mal"},
            {"", "","","", ""},
            {"", "","","", ""}
    };
```

> Estoy tratando de ver cantas veces se repiten unas palabras en un arreglo

Basta con que recorras el arreglo de inicio a fin y cuentes cuantas veces aparece dicha palabra, puedes hacer la operación en una función:

```
int cuenta_palabra(const string *inicio, const string *fin, const string &palabra)
{
    int resultado = 0;

    for (const string *p = inicio; p != fin; ++p)
        resultado += (*p == palabra);

    return resultado;
}
```

Puedes usarlo así:

```
int main() {

    string infoEncuesta[5][5] = {
        { "mal", "bien", "bien", "mal", "pesimo"},
        {"muy bien", "bien","aceptablee","mal", "pesimo"},
        {"aceptable", "mal","mal","mal", "mal"},
        {"", "","","", ""},
        {"", "","","", ""}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        cout
            << "mal aparece "
            << cuenta_palabra(infoEncuesta[i], infoEncuesta[i] + 5, "mal")
            << " veces en la fila "
            << i << '\n';

    return 0;
};
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLbboMwDH0mX@ExaYXBpL30ibK3fcVWTS5NK0vgRCRUmiq@nTnAekGbFDnk5Pg4Pqay9qWqkY/D8Ehc1d1ew4aM863G5k11jvgIjI12FisNzu8LdTK0B2OJybB2iXADifhg3rnqtPMIH@utrLRQitiDgOzxy2KNuxaTyrDzMKc9i0xFJod79EC8gJ7m9FSdVRRUW@262uPeQAmvUik6mBYW4lbupgIFWHgoQXQLyDKbqii6CmQlJIFbwm@RoNdq37V8rVOofuqnQeIkhbNw/mh@6l0KyzujM8QN1nEO8Y403@4zbLWjxsR9Hshx033DPTEW263HXa21HP5MujAusrdxgmZqOMrFuOTrH1RF/cXP0C@NDssmBq6DfRTsq0znYbMZ9QEttlp@kDggi3nfmUPbHBYAZLCen5mOgnASKQeaoUaZmIRRlkJYffLqZjgy@L4Yhh8)</kbd>.

Comment: agradezco mucho él tiempo que te tomaste y la gran ayuda que me impartiste